# Unexplained time offset in QApplication event loop

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm currently working with a program for predicting the locations of satellites in real-time. Something similar to [this](http://gpredict.oz9aec.net/). The underlying library uses system time as input.

```
time_t now(time(0));
```

This program accurately predicts the real-time position of satellites when I run it on a C++ console application using Qt Creator.

The problem is when I use it in a fully-fledged Qt Gui application with a QApplication object in the main function. In the program, the prediction function is periodically by the timer event function. That way I update the positions every 2 seconds. Unfortunately, The output doesn't match (either on the GUI or when I print it). It is like the orbital propagator is using a different time when calculating the satellite positions.

```
void TrackingManager::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
    {
    int nNumSats = m_Satellites.size() ;
    //std::cout << __func__ << " - Number of satellites = " << nNumSats << std::endl;
    std::vector<SatPosition> vSatPositions;

    if (nNumSats >= 0)
    {
        time_t now(time(0));
        std::cout << __func__ << "time(0) = " << asctime(gmtime(&now)) << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < nNumSats; i++)
        {
            // Get satellite names and calculate position, altitude etc
            SatPosition spPos;
            GetInstantPredict(m_Satellites[i], now, spPos);
           

            vSatPositions.push_back(spPos);
        }
        emit UpdateSatPosition(vSatPositions);
    }
}
```

Even more confusing, the program works fine when I run the debugger (GDB on Ubuntu). It is as if GDB somehow manages to "fix" the problem. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. *"The output doesn't match"* -- The output of `time(0)`? What is it supposed to match up with?

Comment: @JarMan Apologies for the confusion. time(0) prints a correct time. It’s the satellite positions that are different, suggesting that running the propagator with QApplication somehow messes up the inner calculation which depends on the difference between system time and that of the underlying orbital propagator. Even more confusing, the program works fine with GDB.

Comment: So some other function that you don't provide the source code for is not giving you the expected output even though the input is correct? I'm not sure how we're supposed to help you with that. And I'm not sure why you think QApplication is the culprit.